# Using Python with Microsoft Graph to pull data from a email

Tags: python, email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

So my question is can you use Python and/or Microsoft Graph to look into your outlook email and pull data out and put it into a excel document.

Here's what I'm trying to do, if there's anything way of doing it please feel free to let me know:

I want to create a folder in my outlook Inbox that get redirected emails. I'd like to make a script that looks at all those emails in that folder and extracts certain data within each email and puts it into a excel document.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you could set up a python script that is connected to the [Outlook REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial). Get the **access token** by following the instruction in the above website and use the **access token** to login. You could set time intervals to re-check your message/mail box and process those data. There could be **functions/parameters** in the api which allows you to **receive update automatically every n seconds** (I have not looked into the details yet). Write your own process function to process data to mine the data for your own usage.

```
import time
def main():
    data = get_my_messages(<your_access_token>)
    time.sleep(5)
    process(data)
main()
```

Such examples python code could be found in the website above.

```
def get_my_messages(access_token):
  get_messages_url = graph_endpoint.format('/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages')

  # Use OData query parameters to control the results
  #  - Only first 10 results returned
  #  - Only return the ReceivedDateTime, Subject, and From fields
  #  - Sort the results by the ReceivedDateTime field in descending order
  query_parameters = {'$top': '10',
                      '$select': 'receivedDateTime,subject,from',
                      '$orderby': 'receivedDateTime DESC'}

  r = make_api_call('GET', get_messages_url, access_token, parameters = query_parameters)

  if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    return r.json()
  else:
    return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)
```